# How to define a logical operator for a truth table from other connectives

Tags: logic

I have a question regarding a logical truth table and a corresponding connective:

If I have two propositions A and B, i want a connective that supports the following definition:

```
A B  A ? B

0 0    1
0 1    1
1 0    1
1 1    0
```

Which connective can be defined to have this behaviour ( 1 = true, 0 = false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector you're looking for is `A NAND B` or `NOT (A AND B)`

[image]